# validate 3 textfields representing date of birth

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have 3 text box fields. to represent a date

eg 
DD MM YYYY

how can i validate only correct data is entered into each text box.
is it a regexpression??

**i need to do this inside the ascx/aspx file rather than the .cs codebehind**

thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you can't enter the date into one text box?  This would make your validation much easier.

Comment: the designs have come with three text boxes :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could validate each field with regexes, but it wouldn't take into account different months with different numbers of days: you could enter invalid dates.

On the server side it could be validated with something like this:

```
DateTime D;
string CombinedDate=String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", YearField.Text, MonthField.Text, DayField.Text);
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(CombinedDate, "yyyy-M-d", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out D)) {
  // valid
} else {
  // not valid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [CustomValidator](https://web.archive.org/web/20210608194151/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/073102-1.aspx) to validate your result input of all 3 controls. Maybe inside that custom validation script you can use regex to validate data.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting them in to a DateTime objects.

```
int day, month, year;

if (Int32.TryParse(dayInput.Value, out day)) {
    if (Int32.TryParse(monthInput.Value, out month)) {
        if (Int32.TryParse(yearInput.Value, out year)) {
            DateTime birthDate = new DateTime(year, month, day);

            if ([birthDate is in valid range])
                // it passes
        }
    }
}
```

I know this isn't very elegant, but you can also test it the same way using the following RegEx

```
[0-9]+
```

However I like my way because I can enter it in to a DateTime field and then test the range to make sure it doesn't exceed the current date and is not below a 100 years before the current date.

Comment: What if dayInput was 12039, monthInput was -1

Answer (score 0):

**Wouldn't validation in the aspx file introduce logic code in the presentation layer?**

I would suggest an AJAX control (there is an AJAX MaskEdit box - alike). They usually okay for these sort of things, look into the AJAX toolkit, if the server you're deploying can support those.

Answer (score 0):

Full example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Web_Layer.WebForm2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <script runat="server">
        protected void ValidateDate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int day=0;
            int month=0;
            int year=0;

            if (!int.TryParse(txtDD.Text, out day))
                day = 0;
            if (!int.TryParse(txtMM.Text, out month))
                month = 0;
            if (!int.TryParse(txtYY.Text, out year))
                year = 0;

            if (((year > 0)) && ((month > 0) && (month < 13)) && ((day > 0) && (day <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month))))
            {
                lblValid.Text = "Valid!";
            }
            else
            {
                lblValid.Text = "NOT Valid!";
            }
        }
    </script>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDD" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMM" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtYY" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" OnClick="ValidateDate"/>
    <asp:Label ID="lblValid" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using dropdowns instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool isValidDate(string datePart, string monthPart, string yearPart)
{
    DateTime date;
    string strDate = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", datePart, monthPart, yearPart);
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate, "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo , System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out date ))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false ;
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't fully validate for correct dates:
bool date = isValidDate("31", "02", "2008");//return true but should be false